# Subtract two fields from different tables

Tags: sql

My query is how I could subtract two values ​​from different tables in SQL. For example, I want a column to subtract the user's free days of vacation. These days must be the difference between the days you have requested in the applications and between the days you have holidays per year. I have two tables:

`sec_users` table that has as fields:

```
pk_user, login, dias_disponibles
```

and another table `solicitud` that has the following fields:

```
pk_solicitud, fk_empleado, n_diassolicitados
```

I have tried the following code:

```
select u.login, (u.dias_disponibles- Coalesce(s.n_diassolicitados,0)) as dias_libres 
from sec_users u 
inner join solicitud s on s.fk_empleado = u.login
```

When I execute the sentence the days of each request appear, it does not do the subtraction, any help?

What I want is for it to come out like this:

```
Login|dias_libres
admin 10
user  15
```

Comment: you are missing `)` try this way `(u.dias_disponibles- Coalesce(s.n_diassolicitados,0)) as dias_libres`

Comment: It would be ideal to perform `inner join` instead of left join

Comment: Can you share some sample data?

Comment: I have made the two changes that you have suggested but still I do the subtraction but of all the requests. What I want is for it to come out like this:

Login|dias_libres
admin|10
user|15

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to group results by usertype.

I think this is what you need:

```
select u.login, 
(u.dias_disponibles- Coalesce(s.n_diassolicitados,0)) as dias_libres 
from sec_users u 

inner join solicitud s 
on s.fk_empleado = u.login

Group by u.login
```

For future problems, please give more info about the current results and some sample data.

Comment: More or less is what I was looking for but it does not make me the function that I wanted.

For example, I have a user whose available days are 20 and that user has consumed 6 days. In the operation that I want to do, I should leave that the user has 14 days left, but I get 16 and I do not know why

Comment: @AlvaroRomanFranco In solicitud table do you have multiple rows with worked hours? Are you sure there are 6 hours worked in solicitud?