# Query SQL to subtract two fields

Tags: sql

My query is that I have two tables, one called `sec_users` with the following fields:

```
pk_user, name, dias_disponibles
```

And another call `solicitud` with the following fields:

```
pk_solicitud, fk_empleado, n_diassolicitados
```

Where `fk_empleado` of the table `solicitud` is the foreign key of `pk_user` of the `sec_users` table

Well, my problem is that I want to create as a small report where I leave the free days that are left to each user, the days he has enjoyed, the casualties he has taken.

For example, the user1, who has 24 days off, creates an application and asks for 4 days off and other for 10 days, since the query must state that the user1 has 10 days left free. I tried this code but it does not work out very well, any help?

```
SELECT u.pk_user, u.dias_disponibles - s.n_diassolicitados AS dias_libres 
FROM   sec_users u
LEFT JOIN solicitud s on s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user
```

The result I get with this statement if for example user1 has created two requests

```
Usuario             Free days  Baja Permisos
==============    ============  ==== ========
Usuario1               20        1        0
Usuario1               10        1        0
```

The result should be like this

```
Usuario             Free days  Baja Permisos
==============    ============  ==== ========
Usuario1                10        1        0
```

Comment: Tip 1: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Tip 2: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Add some sample table data and its expected result.

Comment: Tip 3: If your question doesn't give you an answer, edit your [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48991803/subtract-two-fields-from-different-tables) to include more information, rather than asking a new question.

Comment: It is already modified with {JOIN} but it still gives me the same result that I do not want

Comment: Please back up your expectations with sample data, we're still in the dark why you expect something else from your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUM aggregating function:

```
SELECT u.pk_user, sum(u.dias_disponibles) - sum(s.n_diassolicitados) AS dias_libres 
FROM   sec_users u
LEFT JOIN solicitud s 
on s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user
GROUP BY u.pk_user
```

...and always follow tip 1 from comments!

Comment: That may be worth it but it still gives me results that are not, take a look at my question that I modified it with JOIN

Comment: I still would offer you to write the same group by and the same sum() functions otherwise. If you want to subtract from just the last value, please tell so.

If you group by user, the same user would have 24 days from one side, 14 days on the other side and result would be 10 free days. If it doesn't work, please check values for the same user in both tables and confirm your statements with data.

Comment: are you sure you are BOTH grouping by user and subtracting sum() of the columns? Also, you must NOT group by anything other than the user in this case. You can group by login column too.

Comment: Sorry, I want to subtract the last value of n_diassolicitados of the last request

Comment: But the last request has only 10 days, so the result would be 24-10 = 14...

Comment: Yes, and that's fine, but if user1 creates another request with 4 days, it should be: 24-10-4 = 10

Comment: The second request would have 4 days, so you in fact need ALL the requested days combined, not just the last request. This is achieved by grouping and summing. Try the query I posted, and tell me what is it that does not meet the requirements so I can help you.

Comment: Yes! Your role has been of great help to me, now I'm going to ask something else

Comment: Looks wrong to me. With 20 days available and 5 and 10 days taken, you calculate 20 + 20 - 5 - 10 = 25 where it should be + 20 - 5 - 10 = 5.

Comment: To me, the result that I wanted already appears to me, now I'm going to ask another question

Answer (score 1):

You want to subtract the **sum** of `n_diassolicitados` from the `dias_disponibles`. So don't join the table `solicitud`, but the aggregation query:

```
SELECT 
  u.pk_user, 
  u.dias_disponibles - COALESCE(s.dias_solicitados, 0) AS dias_libres 
FROM sec_users u
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT fk_empleado, SUM(n_diassolicitados) AS dias_solicitados
  FROM solicitud 
  GROUP BY fk_empleado
) s on s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user;
```

Answer (score 0):

The user1 creates another request for 2 days of sick leave, those 2 days of sick leave do not count as requested days. How can I show those two days requested, using the following code:

```
SELECT u.pk_user, u.dias_disponibles - sum(s.n_diassolicitados) AS dias_libres 
FROM   sec_users u
LEFT JOIN solicitud s 
on s.fk_empleado = u.pk_user
GROUP BY u.pk_user
```